# How to integrate input form results into R chunks?

Tags: html, r, forms, r-markdown, blogdown

I am trying to run R scripts on my blog and I need user inputs for few of them (very simple inputs like numbers).

I first built processes around shiny apps but it appears to be extremely slow + I have to deal with Shinyapps.io to host my apps on server (limited to few hours/month for the free plan).

Do you know if there is a possibility to recover the user input in rmarkdown and directly incorporate it in the R chunks through the same Rmarkdown page ? (This page is automatically converted in html when it comes to website, so an html issue would be perfect too).

I hope that someone had the similar issue, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: In order to take User Input, you can Integrate shiny in the Rmarkdown using Runtime Shiny in the YAML. You can also source Rmarkdown script in the R script which can ask for user inputs first and then Run the output accordingly.

Comment: @TimsySuri I think the wrinkle here is that OP wants to run this on a server... I think your solution with Rmarkdown embeding shiny could work.